# Embedding videos in Chatter feed for Lightning Salesforce Community

Tags: lightning, community, chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

I have been trying to embed video links in Chatter feed on Lightning Salesforce Community for which I enabled **"Allow users to compose rich text posts"** and **"Allow Rich Link Previews"** in the chatter settings, but the video preview is not showing up.

[image]

[image]

I see this working in Salesforce classic

[image]

Not sure if I am missing enabling permission for Lightning.

Comment: I am using CustomerAccountPortal template (this is a lightning template) and I am able to see the preview of this video link in the chatter.Is there anything I am missing in the replication steps?

Comment: Hi Swetha! I found the issue. The issue was my the sandbox in which I trying to embed the video and preview the link was on Spring 20 which was not previewing the image. But when in Summer 20 it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was that the sandbox in which I was trying to embed the video and preview the link was on Spring 20 which was not previewing the image. But when in Summer 20 it was working.